# ROT Analysis Tools SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

What ROT (redundant, obsolete, trivial) analysis tools are recommended for SharePoint on-premises and SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

- Both on-prem and Online have support for configurable [Site Closure Policies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-policies-for-site-closure-and-deletion-a8280d82-27fd-48c5-9adf-8a5431208ba5).
- SharePoint Online (O365) has built-in capabilities to [define and enforce Retention Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention-policies?view=o365-worldwide).
- [ShareGate Desktop](https://sharegate.com/products/sharegate-desktop) is a third-party product primarily used for bulk Migrations, but has tools to find unused sites and archive them (rather than just deleting).
- [AvePoint](https://www.avepoint.com/products/hybrid/governance-automation) is a third-party governance automation product that supports both on-prem and Online.
- [Ever Team](https://www.everteam.com/en/data-visualization-and-analytics/file-analytics/) is a third-party file analysis product that works across multiple repository technologies, not just SharePoint.